# How to make dropdown look to the left instead of right

Tags: html, css

So I have an inbox kinda thing and a dropdown for it to show the inbox, but the dropdown is looking to the right and I have it at the right end of my topnavbar so you can barely see the dropdown, here is the CSS for the inbox:

```css
  .notification {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    
    .notification:hover {
      background: red;
    }
    .notification .badge {
      position: absolute;
      top: -7px;
      right: -10px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    } 
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding: 12px 16px;
      z-index: 1;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div style="float:right;" class="dropdown">
    <span className="span3"></span><a href="#inbox" class="notification">
      <span><img src="https://flounder.epizy.com/images/inbox.png" height="25" width="25"/></span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      </div>
      </a>
      </div>
```

So idk how to do it someone pls help!

Comment: What does "looking to the right" mean?

Comment: @enhzflep Like the dropdown's width is to the right

Comment: @enhzflep I added the dropdown css if that helps

Comment: Hello, Remove the `style="float:right;" `the inline style on the div. Hope now it will work

Comment: @MDMNauman I tried that but it just moved the inbox to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what I could do. I think it happened.

```css
 .notification {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    
    .notification:hover {
      background: red;
    }
    .notification .badge {
      position: absolute;
      top: -7px;
      right: -10px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    } 
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      color: black;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding: 12px 16px;
      z-index: 1;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
 <div style="float:right;" class="dropdown">
    <span className="span3"></span><a href="#inbox" class="notification">
      <span><img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/left-arrow-8-458424.png" height="25" width="25"/></span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">Merhaba Test
      </div>
      </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Bro it works good but it looks weird but you got it thank you

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you have some content in `div.dropdown-content` which should look like a list. I'll improvise a bit by adding a list, so here's what the HTML would look like:

```html
<div style="float:right;" class="dropdown">
  <span className="span3"></span><a href="#inbox" class="notification">
    <span><img src="images/inbox.png" height="25" width="25" /></span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul>
        <li>Sunday</li>
        <li>Monday</li>
        <li>Tuesday</li>
        <li>Wednesday</li>
        <li>Thursday</li>
        <li>Friday</li>
        <li>saturday</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Since you want the contents of your dropdown to come below the `a.notification` element, you can simply change the position of the dropdown content wrapper, i.e., `div.dropdown-content`. This is how the CSS would look like:

```css
.notification {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.notification:hover {
  background: red;
}
.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
  right: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  user-select: none;
}
```

I created a [pen](https://codepen.io/pranjalnadhani/pen/YzGJoqp) for this. Make sure to check it out!

Comment: In one point it does work but it just goes straight down

Comment: Updated the answer against your code provided in the question.